# Вывод всплывающего сообщения()resp.data) в поле инпут(где количество товара) вместо стандартного alert

Tags: javascript

```js
 document.querySelectorAll('.addcartpost').forEach(Item => {
           Item.addEventListener("submit", addCart);
    })

     function addCart(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var fd2 = new FormData()
        alerts = this.querySelector('id_quantity')
        const v = this.querySelector('.id_pr').value
        const x = this.querySelector('.id_quantity').value
        fd2.append("id_pr", v)
        fd2.append("quantity", x)
        axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
        axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN"
        axios.post("http://127.0.0.1/catalog/basket/add/", fd2)
            .then(function(resp){

            alerts.setCustomValidity(resp.data)
            //alert(resp.data)
            //modalsubmit.innerHTML = resp

            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err)
            })
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.3.5/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-nnNHpffPSgINrsR8ZAIgFUIMexORL5tPwsfktOTxVYSv+AUAILuFYWES8IHl+hhIhpFGlKvWFiz9ZEusrPcSBQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
 <form class="addcartpost" action="."  method="POST">
<i  class="i bi-file-minus" title="уменьшение">
</i>
<input class="id_pr"  type="hidden" name="id_pr" value="{{product.id_p}}"  required="" id="id_pr">
<input  class="product id_quantity"  name="quantity" type="number"  value="{{product.min_kol}}" min="{{product.min_kol}}"
       step="{{product.min_kol}}"  required="" id="id_quantity" max="{% if product.stock != 0 and product.stock_k13 == 0  %}{{product.stock}}{% elif product.stock == 0 and product.stock_k13 != 0  %}{{product.stock_k13}}{% elif product.stock != 0 and product.stock_k13 != 0 %}{{product.stock|add:product.stock_k13}}{% endif %}">
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="False" id="id_update">
<i  class="bi bi-file-plus" title="увеличение">
</i>
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="addbasket float-rigth">
    <input id="add-toast" class="update" class="button add" type="submit"  value="Купить">
</div>
 </form>
```

Почему то setCustomValidity(resp.data) запускается не сразу а только после второго клика.
И как лучше засунуть его в цикл

Comment: один раз запускается и дальше не отправляет получается

Comment: Вы вешаете обработчик события **submit** на элементы с классом **addcartpost**, однако в коде нет элементов с классом addcartpost, как и нет тега <form>, который бы мог данное событие вызвать...

Comment: в оригинале все правильно тут тоже подправил, все равн оне работает